# setup.py not create proper folders/configuration in mac osx?

Tags: python, macos, setup.py

I am trying to create the setup.py for a script. The setup.py looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='readfile',
      version='1.0',
      description='A flexible module to read ascii files',
      author='author',
      author_email='author@gmail.com',
      url='',
      modules=['readfile'])
```

the script is called readfile.py and doesn't have any additional files or scripts. All I want to do is have setup.py put it on the correct location automatically. So I do

```
python setup.py install
```

This creates a folder

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/readfile-1.0-py2.7.egg
```

However, it doesn't update the python path nor create a directory called readfile in site-packages directly, so I cannot import the module. Am I missing an option that would do any of these?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I had some more trouble afterwards; with various combinations of `setup()` arguments I was able to `import readfile` but none of its modules. In the end, the `setup.py` was fine and I just needed the `__init__.py`, without the extra folder. So the three files (`readfile.py`, `setup.py`, `__init__py`) are in the same folder now and everything works as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a folder at the same level as setup.py called readfile?

Inside that, is there a file called `__init__.py`?

Inside that folder is there also your source file called readfile.py?

That seems to work for me.

The .egg file that you reference is just a zip file that contains everything you need.  There should be no need to update python path or create the readfile directory.  Those things are not needed to import readfile.

Comment: Thanks, I had to do that and change the "modules" argument for "packages". Now it works.